# Passing types to XMLSerializer using variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asp.net-mvc

I'm using the XmlSerializer to de-serialize a response stream from a web request.  This works fine but I want to break this code out so that it's reusable throughout my project.

My aim is to accept XML responses back and convert them to a model object.  As an example of what I've had working in my proof of concept:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyTestModel));
```

I had hoped I could replace the contents of 'typeof' with a variable.  That way I could pass in the model name via the constructor.  However this approach doesn't work.

I did look at generics:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
```

But as I'm programming to an interface I can't declare any methods in the interface as having a type of 'T'.

So I thought rather than spend hours and hours I would reach out to those in the know to get some guidance on how best to code this piece.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Type type = typeof(MyTestModel); ...new XmlSerializer(type);`

Comment: You can use `new XmlSerializer(someVar.GetType())`

Answer (score 2):

Making comment an answer so the question can be closed.

`Type type = typeof(MyTestModel); ...new XmlSerializer(type);`